# Latex for table from research paper "A BERT Baseline for the Natural Questions"

Tags: tables

[image]

I am looking for code for this table

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What have you tried so far? Have you considered writing to the author(s) and asking him/her/them for the code? Do you have reason to believe that the author(s) used LaTeX to generate the table?

Answer (score 1):

Here you are, it is a very simple tabular to make. You have to update the figures yourself.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1}

\begin {document}

\begin{table}
\small
\centering
\caption{A caption with interesting information\label{tab:table}}
\begin{tabular}{@{}@{}r*{6}{c}@{}}

\toprule
                   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Long Answer Dev } 
                   & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Long Answer Test}\\             
                   & P    & R    & F1   & P    & R    & F1  \\
\midrule
DocumentsQA        & 47.5 & 44.7 & 46.1 & 48.9 & 43.3 & 45.7 \\
DecAtt + DocReader & 47.5 & 44.7 & 46.1 & 48.9 & 43.3 & 45.7 \\
\bfseries BERT\textsubscript{joint} (this work)
                   & \bfseries 61.3 & \bfseries 68.4 & \bfseries 64.7
                   & \bfseries 64.1 & \bfseries 68.3 & \bfseries 66.2 \\
\midrule
Single Human       & 80.4 & 67.6 & 73.4 & --   & --  & -- \\
Super-annotator    & 47.5 & 44.7 & 46.1 & --   & --  & -- \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```